# pass new object in one to many relationship in Spring

Tags: java, spring, api, jpa

For example , I have a User entity which has a @ManyToMany relationship with Role entity.
Besides there is a controller to save a new User in DB which receives a User @RequestBody.
Therefor I need to pass some Roles in my json body request to attach them to user I'm sending .
This is my problem :

**How can I pass a Role that has not been saved in DB yet ?**
Actually I'm looking for way to save a role as soon as is passed through the user request .
as far as I know , for example when I want to send new User to save in DB , if it's like this:

```
{
"username" : "user1",
"password" : "pwd",
"roles" : [
      {
        "label" : "ROLE_ADMIN"
      }

]
```

It won't work because this structure expects to get list of existing roles , not roles that have not been saved at the moment .
Hence It must be this way to work :

```
{
"username" : "user1",
"password" : "pwd",
"roles" : [
      {
        "id" : "6"
        "label" : "ROLE_ADMIN"
      }

]
```

And this id property should refer to certain row in database

MyController :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/Users")
public class UserController {

    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Add",method = POST)
    @ResponseBody
    private Response AddUser(@RequestBody User user){

        return new Response("Add single user " ,
                HttpStatus.OK.value(),
                userRepository.save(user));
    }
}
```

User Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "USER_TBL")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }


    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinTable(name = "User_role" ,joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn ( name = " user_id" ), inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    List<Role> roleList;

    public List<Role> getRoleList() {
        return roleList;
    }

    public void setRoleList(List<Role> roleList) {
        this.roleList = roleList;
    }



    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


  public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Role Entity :

```
@Entity(name = "tbl_roles")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    String label;

    public Role() {
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "roleList")
    List<User> users ;

    public Role(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see the part of the code where you try to save the user and the entities too?

Comment: Yes , I putted controller at the end of my question now

Comment: post your entities too man :)

Comment: Sorry , I'll post them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok given the info you provided, I'd first suggest that you create a Service class for that, this is in order to separate the controller from repository operations

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    private User addUser(User user){
       ...
    }
}
```

SN: It is highly suggested to not use the @Autowired on a field level injection (use for example the constructor injection as did above)

As for the addUser method (annotated with transactional) you should first of all retrieve all the roles (I'd go for this option as I don't think the roles tables is going to be massive, otherwise you should findByRoleName() per every role in the list).

```
List<Role> persistedRoleList = rolesRepository.findAll();
```

At this point filter all the roles that are already persisted and add add them to a separate list (you do not have to persist these guys)

```
List<Role> existingRoles = user.getRoleList().stream()
            .filter(persistedRoleList::contains)
            .map(role -> persistedRoleList.get(persistedRoleList.indexOf(role)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see I used the 'contains' and 'get(indexOf())' methods which implies the fact that you adeguately overriden the equals method within the role's class as so

```
public class Role {
   
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Role && this.label.equals(((Role) o).getLabel());
    }
}
```

This of course works perfectly because clearly the role has the label field which is unique

Before hitting the 'save' method you'll have to remove the already persisted roles so

```
user.getRoleList().removeAll(existingRoles);
```

With this out of the way, in the end you will have the new user having all the existing roles with its ids and the non existing ones without the id.
What you're missing now is the cascading on the relationships

So in user you'll have

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

While in role you'll have

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

SN: Important is the LAZY part. You would try to avoid Eager on both sides of a relation ship, might cause loops when mapping the objects.

Now just

```
userRepository.save(user);
```

Finally from the .save() method you'll be returned the persisted entity of type User, which being inside a Transactional method you can just do

```
persistedUser.getRoleList().addAll(existingRoles);
```

to add the already existing roles and mapping them to the user (db too)

Full class:

```
    @Service
    public class UserService {
    
        private final UserRepository userRepository;
    
        private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    
        public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
            this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        }
    
        @Transactional
        public User addUser(User user) {
            List<Role> persistedRoleList = Optional.of(roleRepository.findAll()).orElse(new ArrayList<>());
            List<Role> existingRoles = user.getRoleList().stream()
                    .filter(persistedRoleList::contains)
                    .map(role -> persistedRoleList.get(persistedRoleList.indexOf(role)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
            user.getRoleList().removeAll(existingRoles);
            User persistedUser = userRepository.save(user);
            persistedUser.getRoleList().addAll(existingRoles);
            return persistedUser;
        }
}
```

**EDIT:** I modified the answer because of the loophole on the fact that I was trying to save an already persisted entity

Comment: glad it helped. Kindly accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.project_scheduling.entity.person.Role

Comment: Yes! There was a mistake on my side. Basically I was trying to persist an already persisted method, the code I fixed I've tested personally on a POC and fully works when adding also multiple Roles to a user (both non existing roles and existing at the same time)
Please reread the entire answer as I modified quite a bit of stuff